# mysql version of reddit pgsql hotness function

Tags: mysql, schema

Firstly sorry for my english, it's my first post here, and my english isn't as well as i wish but i hope it'll be enough to get a answer.

So how some of you maybe now reddit put their own source code on [github](https://github.com/reddit/reddit) and i want to use (a little modified by me) version of sql schema with a hotness algorithm. The problem is that schema is written in psgsql and my database use mysql engine.

I tried to convert schema manually but i give up with no effects, so i try again with misc tools and apps, but not even one of them support converting of procedures & functions, and the problem is that i need exactly just that one option.

So, is anyone of you can help me convert the hotness function from [there](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/sql/functions.sql):

```
create or replace function hot(ups integer, downs integer, date timestamp with time zone) returns numeric as $$
    select round(cast(log(greatest(abs($1 - $2), 1)) + sign($1 - $2) * (date_part('epoch', $3) - 1134028003) / 45000.0 as numeric), 7)
$$ language sql immutable;
```

to mysql schema, i would be very grateful :)

Once again sorry for my language, i now that i underestimates the standard :)

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote this function below, and it seem to work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION hot (ups INT(10),downs INT(10),d TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS DOUBLE DETERMINISTIC
RETURN ROUND(LOG(GREATEST(ABS(ups-downs), 1)) + SIGN(ups-downs)*(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d) - 1134028003) / 45000.0,7);
```

I compared its outputs to the outputs of [this Python code](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588), everything seem OK.

Sample run:

```
SELECT hot(20,10,'2013-01-01 00:00:00');

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+----------------------------------+
| hot(20,10,'2013-01-01 00:00:00') |
+----------------------------------+
|                     4957.1202962 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the MySQL syntax for user defined functions, but some PostgreSQL specific parts are:

```
date_part('epoch', $3)
```

Number of seconds of `$3` since the epoch i.e. since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

```
1134028003
```

Number of seconds from epoch to 2005-12-08 07:46:43.

Perhaps this is useful for finding MySQL equivalents.

Comment: But why 2005-12-08 08:46:43 ? Is it because Reddit starts running on that date ?

Comment: @AlbertKam: Why Reddit chose this value is not known. But for reimplementing the algo this is also not necessary to know.