# Converting PGSQL "Create Function" to MySQL

Tags: mysql, function

I never worked with pgsql before  and im trying to convert this function to Mysql... can you give me a hand?

```
create or replace function hot(ups integer, downs integer, date timestamp with time zone) returns numeric as $$
select round(cast(log(greatest(abs($1 - $2), 1)) + sign($1 - $2) * (date_part('epoch', $3) - 1134028003) / 45000.0 as numeric), 7) $$ language sql immutable
```

EDIT:

So far i've got this but it still gives me an error

```
create function hot(ups MEDIUMINT, downs MEDIUMINT, date timestamp) returns BIGINT
select round(cast(log(greatest(abs($1 - $2), 1)) + sign($1 - $2) * (unix_timestamp(date) - 1134028003) / 45000.0 BIGINT), 7)
$$ language sql immutable
```

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BIGINT), 7) $$ language sql immutable' at line 2"

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql version of reddit pgsql hotness function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352696/mysql-version-of-reddit-pgsql-hotness-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That defines the function `hot(ups, downs, date)` (where `ups` and `downs` are integers and `date` is a timestamp-with-time-zone) as this SQL statement:

```
SELECT ROUND( CAST( LOG(GREATEST(ABS(ups - downs), 1))
                    + SIGN(ups - downs) * (DATE_PART('epoch', date) - 1134028003) / 45000.0
                    AS NUMERIC
                  ),
              7
            )
;
```

The `$$ ... $$` notation is a PostgreSQL notation for a multiline string (in this case, containing the SQL query that defines the function). The `LANGUAGE SQL` indicates that the function is in SQL (and *not*, for example, PL/pgSQL). The `IMMUTABLE` (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createfunction.html) indicates that the function doesn't modify the database, and always returns the same results for the same arguments. (In other words, it's a "pure" function.)

- For information on `round`, `log`, `abs`, and `sign`, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-math.html.
- `CAST(... AS NUMERIC)` returns its argument as a number (for example, `CAST('123' AS NUMERIC)` is `123`).
- For information on `greatest`, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html.
- `DATE_PART('epoch', ...)` returns its argument (a date) as a number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 GMT`.